# SVG icons : viewBox not scale size correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, svg, responsive-design, material-ui

I'm using Bootstrap with SVG icons from material.io : https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline
The problem is, SVG icon don't scale up when I copy the code inside in my HTML page.
I set width="48" and height="48" with viewBox="0 0 48 48" but even if the viewport is correct, the size of the picture remains 24x24 pixels...

What can I do to scale the picture to the viewport selected (48x48) ?

I tried width="48", height="48", viewBox="0 0 24 24" and I was close to the result I want.

The code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 48 48" ><path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 3c1.66 0 3 1.34 3 3s-1.34 3-3 3-3-1.34-3-3 1.34-3 3-3zm0 14.2c-2.5 0-4.71-1.28-6-3.22.03-1.99 4-3.08 6-3.08 1.99 0 5.97 1.09 6 3.08-1.29 1.94-3.5 3.22-6 3.22z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/></svg>
```

I know that width and height is for the viewport and viewBox to set size between 0 et viewport limits for the picture, but maybe I miss some details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the drawing's co-ordinates span 20 x 20 so that's what you set the viewBox to. Then the width and height is whatever you want i.e. 48 x 48 in this case.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 22 22" ><path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 3c1.66 0 3 1.34 3 3s-1.34 3-3 3-3-1.34-3-3 1.34-3 3-3zm0 14.2c-2.5 0-4.71-1.28-6-3.22.03-1.99 4-3.08 6-3.08 1.99 0 5.97 1.09 6 3.08-1.29 1.94-3.5 3.22-6 3.22z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/></svg>
```

Comment: Ok, so the size is determined in the SVG and cannot be modified by the viewBox. The only way to grow the drawing is to set higher dimensions in the width and height. But another question : Why with width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 24 24" the size of the picture is still not 48x48 but 40x40 pixels ?

Comment: The width and height is 48. If there's any space then it's just places that's not drawn on. We can make the viewBox 20 x 20 if that's the case. That actually overflows. 22 x 22 seems OK.